# Nopcommerce 2.30 Image Shown in the OrderSummary.cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

Before adding an image to the product variant section the image that was shown for the product in the shopping cart was the first product image in the list of product images for that product. Now the Productvariant image is showing.

How do I keep the productvariant image but revert back to using the first image in the product images as the image that shows in the shopping cart?

```
@if (Model.ShowProductImages)
                    {
                        <td class="productpicture">
                            <img style="border-width: 0px;" alt="@item.Picture.AlternateText" src="@item.Picture.ImageUrl" title="@item.Picture.Title" />
                        </td>
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Nop.Web.Controllers.ShoppingCartController.cs, function PrepareShoppingCartModel:

```
using (profiler.Step("Picture"))
{
    //picture
    if (_shoppingCartSettings.ShowProductImagesOnShoppingCart)
    {
        var picture = _pictureService.GetPictureById(sci.ProductVariant.PictureId);
        if (picture == null)
        {
            picture = _pictureService.GetPicturesByProductId(sci.ProductVariant.Product.Id, 1).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        cartItemModel.Picture = new PictureModel()
        {
            ImageUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(picture, _mediaSetting.CartThumbPictureSize, true),
            Title = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Media.Product.ImageLinkTitleFormat"), cartItemModel.ProductName),
            AlternateText = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Media.Product.ImageAlternateTextFormat"), cartItemModel.ProductName),
        };
     }
}
```

Just change the beginning part of that to:

```
var picture = _pictureService.GetPicturesByProductId(sci.ProductVariant.Product.Id, 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you Soooo Much I never even thought to look there. It works great